# NestJS: Adding verification options to AuthGuard with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to make use of the `AuthGuard` decorator, and the passport JWT strategy, following the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication).

Everything in the documentation works great. But I now want to protect a route with a scope contained in the JWT. So here is a basic jwt payload generated by my application:

```js
{
  "user": {
    "id": "20189c4f-1183-4216-8b48-333ddb825de8",
    "username": "user.test@gmail.com"
  },
  "scope": [
    "manage_server"
  ],
  "iat": 1534766258,
  "exp": 1534771258,
  "iss": "15f2463d-8810-44f9-a908-801872ded159",
  "sub": "20189c4f-1183-4216-8b48-333ddb825de8",
  "jti": "078047bc-fc1f-4c35-8abe-72834f7bcc44"
}
```

Here is the basic protected route being guarded by the `AuthGuard` decorator:

```js
@Get('protected')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
async protected(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello Protected World';
}
```

I would like to add options and restrict the access of that route to the people having the `manager_server` scope into their JWT. So after reading a little bit of the `AuthGuard` code, I thought that I was able to write something like:

```js
@Get('protected')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt', {
    scope: 'manage_server'
}))
async protected(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello Protected World';
}
```

**However, I can't see in the documentation where I could make use of this option.**

I thought that adding an option argument to the `validate` function of the `JWTStrategy` could make the trick, but it does not. Here is my `validate` function (contained in the `jwt.strategy.ts` file):

```js
async validate(payload: JwtPayload, done: ((err: any, value: any) => void)) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    if (!user) {
        return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }
    done(null, user);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and don't hesitate to ask me for more informations in the comments if you need so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you look at the [code](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/a69279e2a001cd872b9e652b7075e068518bac8d/lib/auth.guard.ts) of the AuthGuard, it seems like the `options.callback` function is the only possible customization.

I think instead of writing your own `AuthGuard` that supports scope checks, it is cleaner to have a `ScopesGuard` (or `RolesGuard`) with its own decorater like `@Scopes('manage_server')` instead. For this, you can just follow the `RolesGuard` example in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards), which also just checks an attribute of the JWT payload under the `user` property in the request.

---

### Essential steps

Create a `@Scopes()` decorator:

```
export const Scopes = (...scopes: string[]) => SetMetadata('scopes', scopes);
```

Create a `ScopesGuard`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ScopesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const scopes = this.reflector.get<string[]>('scopes', context.getHandler());
    if (!scopes) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    const hasScope = () => user.scopes.some((scope) => scopes.includes(scope));
    return user && user.scopes && hasScope();
  }
}
```

Use the ScopesGuard as a global guard for all routes (returns true when no scopes are given):

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ScopesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

And then use it on an endpoint:

```
@Get('protected')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@Scopes('manage_server')
async protected(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello Protected World';
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much, using a custom guard was the solution I came with since I posted the question, but your solution of using a custom decorator is something I really like. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Nice class for checking scopes Kim!

I did find several minor typos with the class:

1. You're spreading the scopes parameter so `@Scopes(['manage_server'])` will  raise a compile time warning. I changed `(...scopes: string[])` to `(scopes: string[])`

2. make sure scope includes the variable "scope", not "scopes".
`(scope => scopes.includes(scope));`

Thanks again!

Comment: @leokwanbt14 Thanks! :-) I have updated the answer with your input. I've left in the spread though because then you can use the decorator as `@Scopes('manage_server')` instead of `@Scopes(['manage_server'])` which feels more natural to me.

Comment: I did exactly the same but context.switchToHttp().getRequest(); is always undefined for me @KimKern

Answer (score 7):

I tried a slightly different approach, by extending the AuthGuard guard. I wanted to maintain the ability to use different Passport Strategies, so I included a mixin. Feedback is appreciated.

In your Jwt strategy you could simply return the JwtPaylozd so that the user has a scopes attribute. Then the custom AuthGuard looks like this:

```
import { UnauthorizedException, mixin } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

export function AuthScopes(scopes: string[], type?: string | string[]) {
    return mixin(class ScopesAuth extends AuthGuard(type) {
        protected readonly scopes = scopes;
        handleRequest(err, user, info, context) {
        if (err || !user) {
            throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        if(!this.scopes.some(s => user.scopes.split(' ').includes(s)))
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(`JWT does not possess one of the required scopes (${this.scopes.join(',')})`);
        }
        return user;
        }
    });
  }
```

You can then use this guard like so:

```
@Get('protected')
@UseGuards(AuthScopes(['secret:read'], 'jwt'))
async protected(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello Protected World';
}
```

'jwt' represents the strategy.

Comment: It gives the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: @MohamedSaleh I am guessing you are not including any scopes in your JWT token?

Comment: Yes, I think it was the problem :)