# Howto get req.user in services in Nest JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

In a controller, I add the user object with a guard, inject some service and call that service to get some response. I have removed a lot of code for brevity.

```
@Controller()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
export class UserController() {
   constructor(private readonly userService: UsersService) {
   }

   @Get(':id')
   async findOne(@Param('id') id) {
      return await this.userService.findOne(id);
   }
}
```

Since I have the `AuthGuard`, I now know the user is logged in before entering `:id` route.

In the service I would do something like

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
   async findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
      return await this.usersRepository.findOne({where: {id: id}});
   }
}
```

But of course we want to have some checks that the logged in user has access to the user it is querying. The question is now how do I get the current logged in user. I can send it as a parameter from the controller, but since a lot of the backend would need security checked on the current user, I'm not sure that is a good idea.

```
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@Param('id') id, @Req() req: any) {
   return await this.userService.findOne(id, req.user);
}
```

Ideally, which doesn't work, I would be able to get it in the UserService:

```
async findOne(id: number, @Req req: any): Promise<User> {
   if (id === req.user.id || req.user.roles.contains('ADMIN')) {
      return await this.userRepository.findOne({where: {id: id}});
   }
}
```

Or perhaps through injection in the `UserService` constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(REQUEST_OBJECT) private readonly req: any) {}
```

So, is there a better way to send the user object through the backend than always sending the request object in each function call?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## Update March 2019

Since version v6, you can now inject the `request` object into a [request-scoped provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider):

```
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
}
```

---

## Outdated answer

It's not possible to inject the user (or request) directly into the service. Nest.js does not yet support request-scoped providers. This might change with version 6. Until then, a service does not know anything about a request.

#### Logged in user

You can create a [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) `@User`. Using a decorator is preferable over injecting the request object because then a lot of nest's advantages get lost (like interceptors and exception filters).

```
export const User = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  return req.user;
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard()) 
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@Param('id') id, @User() user) {
   return await this.userService.findOne(id, user);
}
```

#### Roles

You can create a `RolesGuard` that makes sure the logged in user has the required roles. For details, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934148/4694994).

Comment: I still have to send the user object to the services. Since most of the logic resides inside services, this seems like a bad idea. I already have RolesGuard but removed it from the examples since it isn't a solution. Let's say I should only be able to see one group of data inside the database. The entry point in the controller will be the same, but the service should filter out the data. Then again I have to send the user from the controller to the service.

Comment: The roles guard of course is only a solution if you want to restrict the access completely. Sometimes it might make to have different routes with different access levels. But if the logic is complex and lies in the service then of course the service needs all the required data to get passed in. (It is better to use a decorator than to pass in the request object, since otherwise interceptors, error filters won't be called.) As I wrote, this might change in version 6 but I don't know the details, yet.

Comment: Hehe, the downvote was before I saw the "Not possible". I think you edited the post and added that after I voted :) Well, I agree on the decorator, actually I already use that. But it seems a bit strange that this isn't supported. All backends I create will have groups of users where the backend will respond differently on each user. I don't see this as complex, but a normal backend task. So most of the service calls will need the user to validate what it should return.

Comment: I have tried your solution of V6. And command shows error `ReferenceError: Request is not defined`. I did `import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';`

Comment: @Eve Are you using a request-scoped provider?

Comment: For anyone getting an error about request, make sure you have `import { Request } from 'express';` in your imports. By default `Request` is available as a type in `lib.d.ts` so doesn't work properly.

Comment: Be careful, as [per official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#performance), the request-scoped providers will have an impact on application performance. You can read also [this testimonial](https://guxi.me/posts/why-you-should-avoid-using-request-scope-injection-in-nest-js/).

Comment: Does it work with graphql too?

Comment: I have tried your solution for V6. `this.request.user` returns a useless object `{ username: undefined; userId: undefined }`.

Comment: In my service, I'm using the onModuleInit to add intercepts to my axios. In these interceptors, I need the user info. How can I accomplish that using the custom decorator approach?

Answer (score 1):

> @Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST }) worked for me, but I had a lot
> of problems when need inject on anothers services.
>
> Exist a another alternative:
>
> https://github.com/abonifacio/nestjs-request-context
>
> For while its ok.

Inject(REQUEST) doesn't work with any passport strategy due to its global state - [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4581#issuecomment-612974066). https://github.com/abonifacio/nestjs-request-context works fine.

Comment: Is that package still working for you? I have the same issue and need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST }) worked for me, but I had a lot of problems when need inject on anothers services.

Exist a another alternative:

https://github.com/abonifacio/nestjs-request-context

For while its ok.

Comment: Is that package still working for you? I have the same issue and need a solution.